# INNER JOIN with 2 CASE

Tags: mysql, select, case, inner-join

I try to do an INNER JOIN depending of the result of CASE.

```
SELECT *
FROM album
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT album_type CASE album.album_type 
                                           WHEN 1 THEN "album_int" 
                                           WHEN 2 THEN "album_ext" 
                                  END FROM album)
AS type ON type.album_id = album.id
WHERE album.id = 6
LIMIT 1;
```

I have see some examples on this site, but nothing work in my case.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I have 3 tables (album, album_int and album_ext).
- I want to join album_int or album_ext to album.
- if album.album_type = 1 I join album_int,
- else if album.album_type = 2 I join album_ext.
- In album_int and album_int I have a column name album_id (same unique
  id in album)

You do not need any `case expressions` or even a `where clause`.

```
SELECT a.`id`, COALESCE(aint.`something`, aext.`something`) as something, ...
FROM ALBUM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN ALBUM_INT AS AINT ON A.ID = AINT.ALBUM_ID AND A.ALBUM_TYPE = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ALBUM_EXT AS AEXT ON A.ID = AEXT.ALBUM_ID AND A.ALBUM_TYPE = 2
```

---

**AND A.ALBUM_TYPE = 1** as a `join condition` means that ALBUM_INT will ONLY join to ALBUM rows where album_type = 1

similarly:

**AND A.ALBUM_TYPE = 2** as a `join condition` means that ALBUM_EXT will ONLY join to ALBUM rows where album_type = 2

---

please note that an answer previously given by Gordon Linoff uses the same join logic, I have just attempted to emphasize how it meets the described requirements.

Comment: Francis, if the query above fails to meet your expectations what you need to do is provide some `sample data` (as simple text tables) for each of the 3 tables. Then supply an `expected result` from that data. Data & result is a much more effective method than words when trying to explain this type of need.

Comment: It's work great :) But, I get NULL on all colums from album_int or album_ext (depending witch one is link to album). I do: "SELECT album_type, title, date, description, venues, thumbnail_link, folder_link, link". Does it's possible to do not select folder_link and link if the value is NULL?

Comment: I have try: "CASE WHEN link IS Null then '' end AS link" But I still get the colum link

Comment: This is PRECISELY what those joins will do, and this is CORRECT `But, I get NULL on all colums from album_int or album_ext (depending witch one is link to album`.  Now you need to understand `COALESCE()` which is how you can shift the 2 sources of information into a single column). I put a sample above.

Comment: It's work :) Thanks to Used_By_Already, Gordon Linoff and Erik Blessman.
You help me a lot ! So much to lern on SQL :)

Answer (score 2):

`case` doesn't work on tables.  You can use `left join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM album a LEFT JOIN
     album_int ai
     ON ai.album_id = a.id AND a.album_type = 1 LEFT JOIN
     album_ext ae
     ON ae.album_id = a.id AND a.album_type = 2 
WHERE a.id = 6 AND a.album_type IN (1, 2)
LIMIT 1;
```

To get values into the same column, you then need to use `coalesce()`.

Note:  This does the right thing if there is at most one match in each table.

Answer (score 1):

To Join to one of two tables conditionally, create a join column on each table and UNION them together as such:

```
SELECT *
FROM    albums a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS album_type, album_id, colA, colB
    FROM album_int
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS album_type, album_id, colA, colB
    FROM album_ext ) AS b
    ON a.album_type = b.album_type
    AND a.album_id = b.album_id
```

Comment: Yes it's work :) I have change albums a to album a and albums b to album b.
If I want to add an other CASE, I just need to add a new WHEN in the 2 CASE, or I need to do also a new CASE?

Comment: If it's another value for album type, it's just soothe when. Looking at it again, you'd get the same results joining on the album type without the case statements.

Comment: It's dossen't work as expected. I dont get the INNER JOIN with the table (album_int or album_ext). Does it's possible to do a AS on a CASE?

Comment: ON a.album_type = b.album_type should be more ON a.id = b.album_id. Just to be clear, I have 3 tables (album, album_int and album_ext). I want to join album_int or album_ext to album. if album.album_type = 1 I join album_int, else if album.album_type = 2 I join album_ext. In album_int and album_int I have a column name album_id (same unique id in album)